# For loop with if statement in Tornado template. Is it possible?

Tags: python-2.7, templates, for-loop, tornado

Here is some kind of piece in my template markup:

```
{% for filename, uuid, i in files %}
    <div class="content">
        {% if i == 0 %}
            {% for filename, uuid, name in nginx %}
                <span id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">{{ filename }}</span>
                <div id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">
        {% elif i == 2 %}
            {% for filename, uuid, name in apache %}
                <span id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">{{ filename }}</span>
                <div id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">
{% end %}
```

And that is from the server-side:

```
class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    @asynchronous
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        names = ['Nginx', 'Apache']
        files = [(n, file_uuid(f), i) for n, f, i in zip(names, FILENAMES, range(len(FILENAMES)))]
        nginx = [(op.basename(f), file_uuid(f), 'nginx') for f in NGINX]
        httpd = [(op.basename(f), file_uuid(f), 'apache') for f in HTTPD]
        kwargs = {
            'hostname': self.request.host,
            'files': files,
            'nginx': nginx,
            'apache': httpd,
        }
        self.render('template.html', **kwargs)
```

I have different number of files in my lists, nginx and apache, and i'm willing to have them on different tabs.

But here what tornado says:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 837, in _parse
block_body = _parse(reader, template, operator, operator)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/template.py", line 789, in _parse
raise ParseError("%s block cannot be attached to %s block" % (operator, in_block))
ParseError: elif block cannot be attached to for block
```

According to [Tornado docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.3/template.html), there are **for** with **continue/break** and **if/elif/else** support, but
is there for loop + if statement support in tornado templates?
If not, in what way i can implement my purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In templates, indentation is not significant and so you must use an `{% end %}` marker after each compound statement:

```
{% for filename, uuid, i in files %}
<div class="content">
    {% if i == 0 %}
        {% for filename, uuid, name in nginx %}
            <span id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">{{ filename }}</span>
            <div id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">
        {% end %}
    {% elif i == 2 %}
        {% for filename, uuid, name in apache %}
            <span id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">{{ filename }}</span>
            <div id="{{ uuid }}" class="{{ name }}">
        {% end %}
    {% end %}
{% end %}
```

Note that in the case of `if/elif` you only need an `end` after the last `elif`; don't put an `end` between an `if` and its `elif`.